# GetExports and Detecting When not All Imports Could be Satisfied

Tags: mef

I have multiple implementations of an interface `IStartup` that I need to resolve from a `CompositionContainer`. Some implementations have an `[ImportingConstructor]` whose imports are satisfied by another DLL.

It seems that the default behavior when I `container.GetExports<IStartup>()` will return all the `IStartup` implementations that are resolvable and skip those that are not (I understand that most containers work this way). So if a dev forgets to reference an assembly the program will run like nothing is wrong.

How can I detect this condition? I would like to throw an exception if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to allow default values during composition which will allow the part creation and then check in the constructor the imported part's value. If it is the default for the given type, then throw an exception. Here's a sample:

```
[Export(typeof(IStartup))]
public class StartUpThatDoesNotResolve : IStartup
{
    private SomeDependency _sd;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public StartUpThatDoesNotResolve([Import(AllowDefault=true)] SomeDependency sd)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(sd, default(SomeDependency))) throw new ArgumentException("sd");

        _sd = sd;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} started", this.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

Another approach is to use [Mefx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff576068.aspx) to diagnose failures. You could write a script that calls **Mefx** and check the output for specific failures. If you are applying [CI](https://duckduckgo.com/Continuous_integration), You could add this too.

Last but not least, you could download the source of Mefx and study and check out how they diagnose the failures. Then you could try something similar. In the source for [MEF Preview 9](https://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/40606) you will find it under Samples/CompositionDiagnostics. I 've never done this so I can't suggest something concrete on this approach.

Comment: Is it possible to configure MEF to AllowDefault by Default? Not really a fan of using attributes to control dependency inversion.

Comment: You could try MEF Conventions (RegistrationBuilder). Otherwise you could create your own attribute that derives from ImportAttribute and set the default value of AllowDefault to true.